# Disambiguation of "Let me know when the task is completed."

Tags: grammar

The sentence "Let me know when the task is completed." could have two meanings:

1. Let me know the time that the task is supposed to be completed.
2. Once the task is completed, let me know it.

Which of them makes more sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't agree that there is any ambiguity. The sentence

> Let me know when the task is completed.

has your second meaning

> Once the task is completed, let me know [it].

If you want to be told when the task is supposed to be finished, I suggest

> Let me know when the task **will be** completed.